# ResourceContainer message field size limitation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am using a repeated Integer field to query information for a number of places. I am seeing a "No endpoint found for path" error if the number of placeIds is large. Here is the ResourceContainer definition.

```
IDS_REQUEST_CONTAINER = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
   message_types.VoidMessage,
   placeIds=messages.IntegerField(1, repeated=True))
```

If I split the request into requests of size 10 it all works fine. I tried to find an answer on the max size of a repeated field in a ResourceContainer online, but haven't been able to find it. Can anybody point me to a resource or tell me what it would be?

Comment: The answer probably has something to do with the length of the resulting URL. Can you show a few sample requests? If you need to obfuscate things, please replace the text with dummy text of equal length.

Comment: @RoseDavidson I have come to the same conclusion. The parameters are just added as a list on the URL. Each element is added with a placesIds=XXX. Looks like if the maximum length is reached it just sends it without parameters at all. I'll use it in steps of tens for now. Thanks!